# How to extract mixed content in PHP DOMXpath?

Tags: php, parsing, xpath, domxpath

I have following HTML which I am parsing:

```
<ul class="man">
   <li>
      height
       <span>3.3"</span>
    </li>
    <li>
       weight
       <span>45kg</span>
    </li>
    <li>
       date born
       <span>1/12/1979</span>
    </li>

 </ul>
```

I am using below code to parse the above HTML:

```
foreach($xpath->query("//ul[@class='man']/li") as $element)
{
       echo $element->nodeValue;

}
```

But the code returns whole thing which is inside `<li></li>` as height 3.3" and weight 45kg while I need both of that separate as height as label and 3.3" as value same way weight as label and 45kg as value.

I can achieve second that is value using "//ul[@class='man']/ul/span" but can't get label in separate variable.

Any idea to solve this problem?

P.S: There is no way to change the label value as they are coming from server in HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the `<li>`'s children, the first of which is a `DOMText` object containing (for example) the `height` label, and the second will be the `<span>` `DOMElement` object:

```
$data = array();

foreach ($xpath->query("//ul[@class='man']/li") as $element) {

    foreach ($element->childNodes as $child) {
        $content = trim($child->nodeValue);

        if ($child instanceof DOMText && $content != '') {
            $key = $content;
        } elseif ($child instanceof DOMElement && $child->tagName == 'span') {
            $value = $content;
        }
    }

    if ($key !== null && $value !== null) {
        $data[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the code works perfect and I solved the problem. I am very much thanks to you..